# non-zero Jacobian matrix implies linear independece?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, jacobian

Let $\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}y\in \Spec k[T_1,...,T_n]=\mathbb{A}_k^n$ be a closed point, assume $M$ is the corresponding maximal ideal and $R:=k[T_1,...,T_n]$.

Let $f_1,...,f_r\in k[T_1,...,T_n]$ where $r\leq n$, and assume the Jocobian matrix 
$$J_{f_1,...,f_r}:=(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial T_j})_{1\leq i\leq r,1\leq j\leq n}$$
has rank $r$ at $y$, i.e. one of the $r\times r$ minors as a function in $R$ restricts to an unit in $\frac{R}{M}=\kappa(y)$, by renumbering, we may assume it is the first minor.

Then how do we show that the images of $f_1,...,f_r$ in $\frac{M}{M^2}$ (considered as $\frac{R}{M}=\kappa(y)$-vector space) are linearly independent?

Note: This is an intermediate step in the proof of Ulrich Gortz's book, Algebraic Geometry I, Lemma 6.26. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $\frac{M}{M^2}$, assume $\exists \bar{g_i}\in \frac{R}{M}=\kappa(y)$ s.t. $\sum_i \bar{g_i}\cdot f_i=0$.
So $\sum_i g_if_i\in M^2$.

For each $j$, we have $\frac{\partial \sum g_if_i}{\partial T_j}=\sum_i (\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial T_j}f_i+g_i\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial T_j})$.

Note that $\frac{\partial \ \cdot}{\partial T_j}$ sends elements in $M^2$ to $M$, plus that $f_i\in M$, we have
$$\sum_i g_i\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial T_j}\in M$$
View it in $\frac{R}{M}=\kappa(y)$, it is zero.

By assumption $J(y):=J_{f_1,...,f_r}(y)$ as a matrix over $\kappa(y)$ has rank $r$, so for any $(\bar{g_1},...,\bar{g_r})\in \kappa(y)^r$, if $(\bar{g_1},...,\bar{g_r})J=0$, then $(\bar{g_1},...,\bar{g_r})=0$.

But $(\bar{g_1},...,\bar{g_r})J=0$ (in $\kappa(y)$) is exactly $\sum_i g_i\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial T_j}\in M,\forall j$. So we are done.